# How do I make my Simple Products searchable on Google but forward customers to the Configurable product

Tags: magento, search-engine, product

Here is my issue

I have a main configurable product Anne Klein Sunglasses 3104.  Then I have my simple products that are titled more specifically with color and size

```
Anne Klein Sunglasses 3104 color 205/06 size 55 
Anne Klein Sunglasses 3104 color 207/65 size 55 
Anne Klein Sunglasses 3104 color 305/10 size 55
```

I have my simple products hidden so that when customers are on my website they only see the configurable product which then gives them the option to choose the color or size they want.  I don’t want my customers to land on a simple product page and not know that the other colors are available or exist.

My problem is that I am finding that most of my traffic is searching specific colors on google like Anne Klein Sunglasses 3104 color 205/06 and are landing on my simple product pages which does not have all the info and options that the configurable product has.  How can I fix this so that my simple products with the specific colors are still showing up on google but when the customer clicks on the link it takes them to my configurable product page with all the color options.

Comment: Serving different content to the end user and Google bot is considered as [cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking).

You probably should consider another solution. For example, you could modify simple product pages wich are associated to a configurable product to promote it and also encourage users to visit your configurable product page.

Answer (score 2):

Set all your child products to be visible in Catalog and Search. Place the following code in an Observer listing for the `catalog_controller_product_init` event.

```
/**
 * Executed on catalog_controller_product_init if the product is simple and part of a configurable
 * Replaces the current product to be rendered with its configurable parent 
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function replaceSimpleWithConfigurableParent($oObserver)
{
    $oProduct = Mage::registry('product');
    $oRequest = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $aParams = $oRequest->getParams();
    if($oProduct->getTypeId()=='simple'){
        $aParents = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($oProduct->getId());
        if (!empty($aParents) ) {
            $oParent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($aParents[0]);  //assumes that each child product only belongs to SINGLE configurable parent
            $oAction = new Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action($oRequest, Mage::app()->getResponse());
            $oLayoutUpdate = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
            $oLayoutUpdate->addHandle('default');
            $oAction->addActionLayoutHandles();
            $oLayoutUpdate->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable');
            if ($oParent->getPageLayout()) {
                Mage::helper('page/layout')->applyHandle($oParent->getPageLayout());
            }
            $oRequest->setParam('color', $oProduct->getColor());
            $oRequest->setParam('id', $oParent->getId());
            Mage::unregister('product');  //take out the simple child product
            Mage::unregister('current_product');
            Mage::register('product', $oParent);
            Mage::register('current_product', $oParent);  //replace with its parent
            Mage::register('child_product', $oProduct);  //track the child for loading the image, sku and other attributes on PDP
        }
    } 
    return $this;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that (a) it doesn't require an override of core code, and (b) it only requires a single request/response cycle for the server and browser.

Answer (score 0):

I recently read about this same issue on MagentoCommerce.  This thread will help you for sure:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74229/.  I'm going to post the solution here with some small modifications because that thread suggests that you make core mods, which you should never do.

The solution is in two parts.

First,

Copy `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility.php` to `\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility.php`

Edit `\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility.php`.

Find:

```
public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
{
    return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
}
```

and change it to:

```
public function getVisibleInSiteIds()
{
    return array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH, self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH, self::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
}
```

Next, open `app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/product/view.phtml`

Find this:

```
 $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
 $_product = $this->getProduct();
```

Insert this code after it:

```
//redirect to parent product if a child product
$parentId = $_product->loadParentProductIds()->getData('parent_product_ids');
if(isset($parentId[0]))
{
      $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId[0]);
      echo "<script>window. location='".$parent->getProductUrl()."';</script>"; 
}
```

Comment: be aware that this will double the load on your server, and double the page load time for your visitors. You are forcing the browser to request one page, wait for the response from the server, then request another page and wait for that response. not optimal.

Comment: Yes its definitely not optimal but its the only way I can see to do it.

Comment: there is an alternative that involves loading the parent configurable layout in the first request (for the simple child)